# Windows 10 user account issue

Tags: windows-10

My notebook recently updated some windows 10 files after which I lost my admin rights. I am using a bizspark windows 10 product key issued by my company.

Now I am asked to enter an admin user and password each time I install any new software or anything that requires admin rights.

I have logged in to windows 10 using my Microsoft account which was working good with admin rights but unfortunately I lost my admin rights and now with Microsoft account I am unable to perform any admin operations which is really frustrating.

I have made a USB bootable with windows 10 in it and at the time of boot I tried to activate admin account with the command:

```
net users Administrator /active:yes
```

I also tried to assign admin rights to the DefaultAccount:

```
net localgroup Administrator DefaultAccount /add
```

After I restart my laptop I find the only microsoft account.

How do I make an active admin account?

I tried to enable admin account with normal cmd but access was denied also now a big problem is that my cmd is not working  says "This file doesn't have a program associated"

Comment: Run cmd as administrator.. try those commands

Comment: @TechieGossip it asks me for an admin username and password since my microsoft account doesn't have admin rights.

Comment: Login as local administrator

Comment: @TechieGossip Well i don't have one i just used my microsoft id at the time of installing windows 10

Comment: Can you go cmd type lusrmgr.msc.. if you Get users there.. enable administrator and enter password try

Comment: @TechieGossip Sorry i get this error when i open cmd "This file doesn't have a program associated"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61089/discussion-between-melvin-and-techie-gossip).

Answer (score 1):

Restart Your System and boot using Windows 10 Installation Media (DVD/USB)

Select the language - Next
Go To Repair Your Computer

1. Troubleshoot → Advanced options → Command Prompt
2. Choose Command Prompt from the menu. Run Diskpart
3. `List Volume` You can see which Drive is your OS installed Drive. Note Down drive letter Example In my case C drive
4. `Exit` from Diskpart. Type `c:\`
5. `cd windows` Enter, `cd System32` Hit enter Again.
6. `copy utilman.exe utilman1.exe` Hit Enter. Backuping the utilman tool
7. `copy cmd.exe cmd1.exe` Hit Enter. Backuping Command Prompt.
8. `Del utilman.exe` Delete the Original utilman tool exe.
9. Type `rename cmd.exe utilman.exe`. this will replace the uTilmanager to command Prompt.
   Refer the commands with below screen shot. Restart Your system.

[image]

One You Restart your PC. Boot as normal. When You get the Login Screen You Can see Ease to access. Where we have replaced with Command Prompt.

[image]

Once you Click on that the Command Prompt will work for You.

Type `control userpasswords2`

You Get Prompt of  User Accounts

[image]

**You can Change your Standard User to administrator user. Reset the passwords of any users**

- Select the user (which done have admin rights) → Properties → Group Membership Tab →  Change to Administrator
- Commands also will work. Type `net localgroup administrators {user_name} /add`

---

- Reset Administrator Password and Login through Local Administrator. Give the Permission to Microsoft Account user which you are using.

---

- Add New user with Administrator rights and Transfer all user profile data to new user. After that link your Microsoft account to local user.
- Using Gui just Click on Add and Via command Prompt Type `net user melvin /add` Give admin Rights Type `net localgroup administrators melvin /add`

Try to Login all will be set.

Last Option is you have to revert the things you Changed in System 32.

---

Again restart Your System using Windows 10 Installation Media.

Select the language - Next
Go To Repair Your Computer

1. Troubleshoot → Advanced options → Command Prompt.
2. Type `c:\` Hit Enter, `cd windows` Enter, `cd System32` Hit enter Again.
3. Type `Del utilman.exe`
4. Type `rename utilman1.exe utilman.exe`